# Can I use variable substitution in hive for a list of values?

Tags: variables, hadoop, hive

While the [documentation](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/language_manual/var_substitution.html) specifies how one can substitute a variable, it does not seam to support lists.

I have a query that needs to run for each day of a month, so I want to do something like this:

```
for day in days:
  ALTER TABLE foo ADD PARTITION(${day=hiveconf:day});
```

Is there a way to do this without! using some kind of scripting language like python/bash.

I have a python implementation, but it need to start a new hive process for each query. Besides being ugly, this has bad performance for small queries because of the hive start-up-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a great way to do this, and I'm pretty certain there's no way at all to do it without a secondary scripting language. But it's not too painful in something like bash:

```
hive_script=foo.hql
if [ -e "$hive_script" ]
then
    rm $hive_script
fi
days="1 2 3 4 5"
for day in $days
do
    echo "ALTER TABLE foo ADD PARTITION(day=$day);" >> $hive_script
done
hive -f $hive_script
rm $hive_script
```

Same strategy could be used in python: have the script generate all of the commands you want to execute, writing them to the same file. Then just execute that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its indeed ok for a simple thing like this but one wants to implement a general purpose solution you get all the fun with parsing arrays and combining them for a arbitrary list of variables to substitute.  
  
But since its seams there is no solution in hive ( and I don't blame them ), this is the next best thing.  
  
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`--hivevar VALUES=1,2,3,4`

It does a dumb substitution of the values in the query. So, if in your query you write

`...WHERE values in (${VALUES})`

it would translate to

`...WHERE values in (1,2,3,4)`

Also, if your values are string, you need to surround the entire list with double quotes like: 
`--hivevar VALUES="'1','2','3'"`